# How to know if a service is correctly loaded?

Tags: macos, xcode, big-sur, wireshark

While inspecting why `rvictl -s <phoneUDID>` command on a Macbook (Intel) running Big Sur, is failing to start/create a virtual interface for the connected iPhone, when issuing the command:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/Apple/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.rpmuxd.plist
```

I get:

```
/Library/Apple/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.rpmuxd.plist: service already loaded
Load failed: 37: Operation already in progress
```

Does this mean the service is not fully loaded yet? If so, why does the service hangs loading?